# Reading the stdout with Java from Linux does not work

Tags: java, linux, stdout

I am trying to read the `stdout` from my simple Linux shellscript.

`test.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "I am waiting"
sleep 2s
exit 0
```

`ShellScriptExecutorTest.java` looks like:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class ShellScriptExecutorTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("sudo", "bash", "./test.sh");
            processBuilder.directory(new File("/home/"));
            processBuilder.inheritIO();
            Process process = processBuilder.start();

            InputStream is = process.getInputStream();  
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);  
            String line;  
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {  
              System.out.println("--> " + line);  
            }  
            
            int exitValue = process.waitFor();
            System.err.println("exitValue: " + exitValue);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

If I execute the code above I get:

```
[root@localhost home]# javac ShellScriptExecutorTest.java
[root@localhost home]# java ShellScriptExecutorTest
I am waiting
exitValue: 0
```

So, obviously the `BufferedReader` didn't 'read' anything otherwise it had write:

```
--> I am waiting
```

on the console.

How can I figure out my error?

Comment: I would assume the BufferedReader does not get the input as long as there is no new line on the console. At least that's the way most consoles work.

Comment: Please add: What do expect to read at your console?

Answer (score 1):

Delete this line

```
processBuilder.inheritIO();
```

Check out what it does:

```
public ProcessBuilder inheritIO()
Sets the source and destination for subprocess standard I/O to be the same as those of the current Java process.
```

Taken from here [java api](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#inheritIO--)

And that is exactly what you are seeing at your console.
The console output of your child-process is "routed" to your process.

I am not sure what you would like to see? But sounds like you would like to see the INPUT to your child process?

Bottom line is you need to get a more basic understanding of child-processes and streams.